# How can I get attribute of ajax response

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

```
resp.getWriter().write("msg=1?id=" + l1);
```

in the below code I can get `responseText` but how can I get the attribute of response text.

ajax code:

```
function updatecategories(cu) {
  var r1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (r1.readyState == 4 && r1.status == 200) {
      if (r1.responseText = "1") {
        // how to get id from the response.
      }
    }
  };
  r1.open("GET", "../category_update?action=catu&cu=" + cu, true);
  r1.send();
}
```

Comment: how is your response looks like?

Comment: resp.getWriter().write("msg=1?id="+l1);

Comment: Can you elaborate the question, what attribute are you looking for? Adding example with the expected result will make it easy

Comment: Add your servlet code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set small information into the response header as name-value pairs. That way it's easier to retrieve.

Set the response header

```
response.setHeader("msg", "1");
response.setHeader("id", l1); //value must be a String.
```

Retrieve the information

```
if (r1.readyState == 4 && r1.status == 200) {
    var msg = r1.getResponseHeader("msg");
    var id = r1.getResponseHeader("id");
}
```

---

Side note: when setting information into the response header make sure you always use a unique `name`. Avoid using names like

- `status`
- `date`
- `content-length`
- `content-type`

since they are already reserved.